# PHP with namespaces and Smarty error: unknown tag "cycle"

Tags: php, namespaces, smarty, spl-autoload-register

Everyone!

I'm working with PHP and Smarty in my project.
I'm using namespaces and I'm having a problem when I call Smarty functions, for sample **cycle**

I'm having this error: **Syntax Error in template ".\sys\adm\template\fields\inputFileField.tpl" on line 23 "{cycle values="um,dois"}" unknown tag "cycle"**

I'm using spl_autoload_register to auto load classes in project:

```
function smartyAutoloader($className) {
    $file = "sys/classes/smarty/$className.class.php";

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I did not change the namespace in Smarty class, so I'm importing Smarty this way:

```
use \Smarty;
```

If I comment the **cycle** code, my code works correctly.

Follow is the problemmatic code:

```
{for $x = 0 to 10}
    {cycle values="um,dois"} {*line 23 on inputFileField.tpl*}
{/for}
```

***I'm not knowing to use namespace and Smarty in same project. I'm sure this error is because of namespaces.
Can someone help me?***

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a way that we can see `Line 23` from `inputFileField.tpl` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!
This is part of my code:
`{for $x = 0 to 10}
 {cycle values="um,dois"} {* line 23 *}
{/for}`

Comment: What shall this clipping code actually do?

Comment: This is only a test, because I'm using namespaces in my project and my Smarty custom functions didn't was working. Then, I thought in do a simple code to test and I saw that none of smarty functions was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [post at the Smarty forum](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=744&sid=2f72dcfa2b3fc98518311711926a2719)

The problem seems to be a wrong or relative path to the plugin folder.
After setting the path to the plugin folder absolut, it works fine, even with namespaces.

Have also a look at the [Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.plugins.dir.tpl):

> **Technical Note**
>
> For best performance, do not setup your `$plugins_dir` to have to use
>   the PHP include path. Use an absolute pathname, or a path relative to
>   `SMARTY_DIR` or the current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set setPluginsDir like this:

```
$dirSep = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$smarty->setPluginsDir($path."smarty".$dirSep."libs".$dirSep."plugins");
```